# Auto Fit Windows Vertically in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I'm just wondering if there's a way(either by using regedit or any "hack") to make explorer windows(and perhaps apps windows) to automatically fit vertically by default instead of using win+shift+up keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe Eusing's **[Auto Window Manager](http://www.eusing.com/WindowManager/WindowManager.htm)** is for you. while AWM doesn't do exactly what you have in mind, it will add a whole rake of new options to the default windows management, such as program start rules, alignments, transparency etc.

*AWM is freeware and works with Windows 7.*

Comment: thnk, i'll check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can simply use the top resize edge of the window and drag it all the way to the top of the screen. This will autofill the window vertically. See [AeroSnap](http://blogs.msdn.com/e7/archive/2009/03/17/designing-aero-snap.aspx).

Comment: Or double-click the top or bottom edge of the window.

Comment: Thnx, but i already know this. I'm trying to find a way to automatize it either that or make Windows remember how i like my windows

Comment: Molly's got it then. Check his answer. Have fun.